# Powershell script to find if a user has logged in since last reboot

Tags: windows-7, powershell, login

So I've been working on a Powershell script that needs to detect if an interactive logon has happened since the last reboot. I can force the system to restart before I launch the task, but I'd like to add some intelligence to the script.

Caveats:

- Must use Powershell.
- Can't require special power packs or addins.
- Can't use Active directory commands. (No get-qaduser)

I am able to get the last time the system rebooted already:

```
$date = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | %{$_.LastBootUpTime} 
$RebootTime = [System.DateTime]::ParseExact($date.split(".")[0],'yyyyMMddHHmmss',$null)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are we talking a specific user or any user?

Comment: @Zypher - Any user. We mainly need to know if someone has logged on locally to the machine. I've tried looking in the win32_NetworkLoginProfile WMI object, but the LastLogon property doesn't hold the correct time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're set on using WMI, you can get `LastBootUpTime` a bit cleaner:

```
PS C:\> $wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
PS C:\> $rebootTime = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LastBootUpTime)
PS C:\> $rebootTime
Tuesday, May 24, 2011 3:18:28 PM
```

Taking that, we search the `Security` Event Log, since `$rebootTime`, for the most recent, *successful*, eventID `4624` containing `Logon Type 2` -- Interactive Logon:

```
PS C:\> $entry = Get-EventLog -After $rebootTime -LogName Security | Where-Object {($_.EventID -eq '4624') -and ($_.EntryType -eq 'SuccessAudit') -and ($_.Message | Select-String "Logon Type:\t\t\t2")} | Select-Object -First 1
PS C:\> $lastLogon = $entry.TimeGenerated
PS C:\> $lastLogon
Tuesday, May 24, 2011 3:19:34 PM
```

Then, a quick compare:

```
PS C:\> $lastLogon -gt $rebootTime
True
```

The above code can be dumped into a script and/or executed on a remote computer.  I only ran the commands interactively to demonstrate the example output.

Comment: Should you maybe add a "| sort-object TimeGenerated " before you do the select -first 1?

Comment: @Mike: In my testing `Get-EventLog Security` returned entries in reverse chronological order.  But your suggestion wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Sorry...I'm a DBA.  I don't trust sorting that isn't explicit.  As soon as you trust it, it tricks you.

Comment: @Mike No worries! If this had been a more specific question I would certainly recommend verifying the `ORDER BY`. @DolyKnuckle's question asked how to determine *if* an interactive logon had occurred since the last reboot, not necessarily the most recent since reboot -- so I cut a corner there.

Comment: Good point.  Again, as a DBA, I see a red flag whenever there's a "TOP n" and no "ORDER BY".  In looking at the code, though, the -after in the get-eventlog would cause it to only return something if there was a login.  That means that the final -eq isn't needed, right?

Comment: @Mike You're correct, the comparison is superfluous. The above was example code to get the OP headed in the right direction. In production, checking that `$lastLogon` is not null should suffice. I wanted to demonstrate for the OP the simplicity of working with datetimes in Powershell.

Comment: Makes sense to me.